# Server Socket - Sending a test message to detect connection

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to use server sockets to set up a connection between a client and a server. I'm also not using `java.nio`.

The problem is that I'm constantly sending a test message, and detecting whether if it is successful in sending the message (the client is still connected), if not, then the client is disconnected.

Shown here:

```
    try
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader in_2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        while(stopThread)
        {
                if(in_2.ready())
                {
                    String message = in_2.readLine();
                    dt = new DateTime();

                    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    server.detect(message, dataSets, out);

                    dataSets.add(message);
                    GUI.textArea_1.append(message + "\r\n");
                    GUI.textArea_1.setCaretPosition(GUI.textArea_1.getDocument().getLength());
                }
                else
                {
                    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    out.println("Testing Connection \r\n");
                    if(out.checkError())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            socket.close();
                        } 
                        catch (IOException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        stopThread = false;
                        GUI.textArea.append(userName + " disconnected \r\n");
                        GUI.textArea.setCaretPosition(GUI.textArea.getDocument().getLength());
                        server.inputDataForm(userName, dt, dataSets);
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }

        }
```

The problem is that the `Thread.sleep(3000)` is actually interfering with getting data, since after 3 seconds, I will get a huge amount of data (because I stopped the thread for 3 seconds).

Now, what I proposed is a anonymous class in the else statement.

```
class runThread implements runnable
{
     void run()
     {
          //Put the else statement here
     }
}
```

But the stopThread = false is not a constant, which I'm trying to control.

Other threads I've searched only puts variables inside main inside the anonymous class, but I need stopThread to stop the while loop if the client is disconnected.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make a class that implements runnable but also has the method stop();

```
public class MyRunner implements Runnable(){
    MutableBoolean stop = false;
    public void run(){...}
    public void stop(){
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm... how would stop be called then?

Comment: actually in the end I created a thread at shutdown() that would monitor the MutableBoolean, and both stop when the client disconnects.

Comment: If it works then good!  You would call stop() by creating the MyRunner then calling stop from outside the thread somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Consider setting a short [timeout on your socket.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) This will allow you to control how long your thread will block while waiting for data from the socket.

If data are not quickly available, a very specific `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` will be raised. You can handle this exception by checking your `stopThread` flag. If it is set, you can return from the method. Otherwise, the socket is still valid and you can try another read operation with timeout.

If any other exception type is thrown, your socket is probably no longer valid.

```
  socket.setSoTimeout(20); /* 1/50th of a second. */
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  while (!stop) {
    try {
      String message = in.readLine();
      if (message == null) 
        handleEOF();
      else
        handleMessage(message);
    } catch(SocketTimeoutException ignore) {
      /* Loop back to check "stop" flag. */
      continue;
    } catch(IOException ex) {
      handleDisconnection();
      break;
    }
  }
```

By the way, if you are using Swing, remember that [you can only modify graphical components from Swing's Event Dispatch Thread,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and you can't tie up the EDT in long-running operations like this socket handling. You should be passing tasks from this thread to Swing's [`invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) utility.